# Difference between singleton methods

Tags: c++, singleton

Is there any difference between these methods, other than the obvious that first return an object and second returns the address where the value of myclass is stored?
I'm asking because I rarely see the first method, in many sources, even of big enterprises such as Aeonsoft I always see method 2 being used. However some programmers don't like `&` with `return`, please enlighten me about this.

```
static myclass& getinstance()
{
    static myclass a;
    return a;
}

static myclass* getinstance()
{
    static myclass a;
    return &a;
}
```

**EDIT**
Oh guys my bad, I forgot the `&` on the first method

Comment: Regarding your edit, I don't understand why anyone would use a pointer in this context. A reference is more explicit; just make sure `myclass` is non-copyable.

Comment: Yes, I have the same opinion as yours and everyone else, what I don't understand is why the second method is so more used, as I said, even on big enterprises sources, maybe I haven't seen much recent code enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one makes no sense, because it returns a *copy*. The latter is a bit silly because there's no need for a pointer.

The usual way for a singleton creation function is to return a *reference*:

```
static Foo & getFoo()
{
    static Foo impl;
    return impl;
}
```

Comment: I just forgot the `&`, please reconsider the question

Answer (score 2):

The first API is better, because returning a reference rather than a pointer indicates that the object will exist (i.e. no need to test for `NULL`). Both ways let you return polymorphic objects (i.e. a subclass of `myclass`), so there is no difference there. You should prefer returning a reference when you can.

Answer (score 1):

Now since you've corrected the first method...

It's just a matter of style which one would be preferred. People who started with C and moved to C++ later might naturally use a pointer without even thinking about using a reference.

---

The first method doesn't actually create a singleton, since it returns a *copy* of the object.

One simple subtle change could fix that:

```
static myclass & getinstance()
{
    static myclass a;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I disagree it's purely a matter of style. References and pointers have different semantics, ergo it can't possibly be simple arbitrary preference. Pointers do not have the intended semantics here, so a reference is better. You are *referring* to an object, not pointing to one (a pointer being a nullable reference).

Comment: @GManNickG, both the pointer and the reference are capable of getting the job done, and I don't consider the semantic difference to be worth worrying about. I do agree that the reference is a better fit usually, but a pointer can give you more flexibility. You can use your `getinstance` method to inject a test object for example. I've also run into a situation where mixing libraries and DLLs caused more than one singleton to be created, fixing that required a table of pointers.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Manual assembly also gets the job done but we don't ever seem to consider that, and I think the reason why is that it's more than just getting the job done, it's getting it done well. A valid value for a pointer (any pointer) is `nullptr`. Ergo, if the function returns a pointer I have to check for null before I dereference it, by the contract implicit with a pointer. People object with "but it's in the contract of my function's documentation that the pointer never be null!", to which the reply is "so let the compiler help enforce that and document it with a reference".

Comment: And I'm sure you can come up with scenarios where pointers might work better (and you've surely got much more experience there!), but those are exceptions, not the rule. (Also, a table of pointers under the hood can still ultimately return a reference. I've recently switched to using `std::reference_wrapper<T>` in places where I needed non-null `T*`'s, but needed copy-semantics.)

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you're returning a copy of the `a` object. In the second you're returning a pointer to it. So the first function turns your singleton into a *multi*-ton.

I'd also modify the second to return a reference instead of a pointer.

```
static myclass& getinstance()
{
    static myclass a;
    return a;
}
```

After your edit, it looks like you are returning a reference to the static object in the first function, instead of a copy. In this case, there is no difference except callers of the function will need to dereference the pointer in the second case.

As a rule of thumb, always accept / return references unless you want to be able to handle a `nullptr` input / return value.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to return by reference.

This is because there will never be any confusion on who owns the object. If you return by pointer the user may erroneously think they need to delete the pointer as the ownership semantics are not clear.